# Missing rows after updating SQL Server index key column

Tags: sql-server

"T-SQL Querying" book ([http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Querying-Developer-Reference/dp/0735626030](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626030)) has an interesting example, where, querying a table under default transaction isolation level during clustered index key column update, you may miss a row or read a row twice. It looks to be acceptable, since updating table/entity key is not a good idea anyway. However, I've updated this example so that the same happens, when you update non-clustered index key column value.

Following is the table structure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE master;
IF DB_ID('TestIndexColUpdate') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE TestIndexColUpdate;
GO
USE TestIndexColUpdate;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Employees', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Employees;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees
(
empid CHAR(900) NOT NULL, -- this column should be big enough, so that 9 rows fit on 2 index pages
salary MONEY NOT NULL,
filler CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT('a')
);
CREATE INDEX idx_salary ON dbo.Employees(salary) include (empid); -- include empid into index, so that test query reads from it
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(empid);

INSERT INTO dbo.Employees(empid, salary) VALUES
('A', 1500.00),('B', 2000.00),('C', 3000.00),('D', 4000.00),
('E', 5000.00),('F', 6000.00),('G', 7000.00),('H', 8000.00),
('I', 9000.00);
```

This is what needs to be done in the first connection (on each update, the row will jump between 2 index pages):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE TestIndexColUpdate;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Employees SET salary = 10800.00 - salary WHERE empid = 'I'; -- on each update, "I" employee jumps between 2 pages
END
```

This is what needs to be done in the second connection:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE TestIndexColUpdate;

DECLARE @c INT
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT salary, empid FROM dbo.Employees
    if @@ROWCOUNT <> 9 BREAK;
END
```

Normally, this query should return 9 records we inserted in the first code sample. However, very soon, I see 8 records being returned. This query reads all it's data from the "idx_salary" index, which is being updated by previous sample code.
This seems to be quite lax attitude towards data consistency from SQL Server. I would expect some locking coordination, when data is being read from index, while its key column is being updated.

Do I interpret this behavior correctly? Does this mean, that even non-clustered index keys should not be updated?

**UPDATE:**
To solve this problem, you only need to enable "snapshots" on the db (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON). No more deadlocking or missing rows. I've tried summarize all of this here: http://blog.konstantins.net/2015/01/missing-rows-after-updating-sql-server.html

**UPDATE 2:**
This seems to be the very same problem, as in this good old article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I interpret this behavior correctly?

Yes.

> Does this mean, that even non-clustered index keys should not be updated?

No. You should use a proper isolation level or make the application tolerate the inconsistencies that `READ COMMITTED` allows.

This issue of *missing rows* is not limited to clustered indexes. It is caused by moving a row in a b-tree. Clustered and nonclustered indexes are implemented as b-trees with only tiny physical differences between them.

So you are seeing the exact same physical phenomenon. It applies every time your query reads a range of rows from a b-tree. The contents of that range can move around.

Use an isolation level that provides you the guarantees that you need. For read-only transactions the snapshot isolation level is usually a very elegant and total solution to concurrency. It seems to apply to your case.

> This seems to be quite lax attitude towards data consistency from SQL Server. I would expect some locking coordination, when data is being read from index, while its key column is being updated.

This is an understandable request. On the other hand you specifically requested a low level of isolation. You can dial all the way up to `SERIALIZABLE` of you want. `SERIALIZABLE` presents you as-if serial execution.

*Missing rows* are just *one* special case of the many effects that `READ COMMITTED` allows. It makes no sense to specifically prevent them while allowing all kinds of other inconsistencies.

---

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE TestIndexColUpdate;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

DECLARE @c INT
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Employees WITH (INDEX (idx_salary))
    WHERE empid > '' AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), empid) > '__'
        AND salary > 0
    if @count <> 9 BREAK;
END
```

Comment: It's interesting to see that if you remove loop from "reading" transaction and put it into REPEATABLE READ isolation level (the level, which solves the problem), you get into into deadlock error after just few runs.

Comment: I don't think REPEATABLE READ is enough anyway. A row can be moved from the range that has not been read to the range that has already been read. The row can still go missing.

Comment: But this is exactly what was happening in my case before REPEATABLE READ (if you replace "range" with "page").

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding. I'm saying that with RC and RR levels the missing rows problem can happen. RR does not prevent it.

Comment: What if we look at particular example and not just any case of "missing rows"? In my example, there are no ranges, it's just that the row is jumping between index pages. It looks like RR acquires the necessary locks, but it results in a deadlock very soon.

Comment: This is not about pages. You could create the same result with a single page. This is about rows moving to a different place in index-order. Here, index order is (salary, empid). The select query is being executed by scanning the index in-order row-by-row.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not correct. SQL Server reads data into memory in pages (logically, from cache or physically). Try to remove 1 row in the middle and rebuild the index, so that it takes only 1 page. The problem does not repeat itself!

Comment: Probably a timing issue. Scanning 10 rows is insanely quick. Maybe SQL Server keeps the page latched while it emits those rows. Add a filter on a lob type that does nothing (like `LobColumn <> 'doesnotexist'). That forces the latch to be released between rows.; Also, make the loop write to a temp table and emit nothing. SSMS is very slow. You might well have 99% of the time spent in SSMS code. I did not get what you wanted to say with the comment about pages. It is correct but does it contradict what I say?

Comment: According to the execution plan the select uses a table scan. It no longer uses the index with one page. That's why the problem disappeared. Force index usage with a hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68179/discussion-between-konstantin-and-usr).